# Error installing FOSUserBundle on symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, composer-php, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.4

inside the oficial documentation it say as a first step

`$ composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0"`

And this return me this errors

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v2.1.2
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v2.1.1
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v2.1.0
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v2.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v2.0.1
    - Conclusion: remove paragonie/random_compat v9.99.99
    - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/user-bundle ~2.0 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.2, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install paragonie/random_compat v9.99.99
    - friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v2.0.0 requires paragonie/random_compat ^1 || ^2 -> satisfiable by paragonie/random_compat[1.0.10, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.2.0, v1.2.1, v1.2.2, v1.2.3, v1.3.0, v1.3.1, v1.4.0, v1.4.1, v1.4.2, v1.4.3, v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.10, v2.0.11, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4, v2.0.5, v2.0.6, v2.0.7, v2.0.8, v2.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[1.0.10, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[1.0.2, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[1.0.3, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[1.0.4, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[1.0.5, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[1.0.6, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[1.0.7, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[1.0.8, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[1.0.9, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[1.1.0, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[1.1.1, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[1.1.2, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[1.1.3, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[1.1.4, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[1.1.5, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[1.1.6, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v1.0.0, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v1.0.1, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v1.2.0, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v1.2.1, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v1.2.2, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v1.2.3, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v1.3.0, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v1.3.1, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v1.4.0, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v1.4.1, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v1.4.2, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v1.4.3, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.0, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.1, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.10, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.11, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.12, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.13, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.14, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.15, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.16, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.17, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.2, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.3, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.4, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.5, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.6, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.7, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.8, v9.99.99].
    - Can only install one of: paragonie/random_compat[v2.0.9, v9.99.99].
    - Installation request for paragonie/random_compat (locked at v9.99.99) -> satisfiable by paragonie/random_compat[v9.99.99].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

This are the list of my installed bundles

```
behat/transliterator                     v1.2.0   String transliterator
cocur/slugify                            v3.1     Converts a string into a slug.
composer/ca-bundle                       1.1.2    Lets you find a path to the system CA bundle, and includes a fallback to the Mozilla CA bundle.
doctrine/annotations                     v1.6.0   Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/cache                           v1.7.1   Caching library offering an object-oriented API for many cache backends
doctrine/collections                     v1.5.0   Collections Abstraction library
doctrine/common                          v2.9.0   Common Library for Doctrine projects
doctrine/dbal                            v2.8.0   Database Abstraction Layer
doctrine/doctrine-bundle                 1.9.1    Symfony DoctrineBundle
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle           1.3.3    Symfony Bundle for Doctrine Cache
doctrine/event-manager                   v1.0.0   Doctrine Event Manager component
doctrine/inflector                       v1.3.0   Common String Manipulations with regard to casing and singular/plural rules.
doctrine/instantiator                    1.1.0    A small, lightweight utility to instantiate objects in PHP without invoking their constructors
doctrine/lexer                           v1.0.1   Base library for a lexer that can be used in Top-Down, Recursive Descent Parsers.
doctrine/orm                             v2.6.2   Object-Relational-Mapper for PHP
doctrine/persistence                     v1.0.0   Doctrine Persistence abstractions.
doctrine/reflection                      v1.0.0   Doctrine Reflection component
fig/link-util                            1.0.0    Common utility implementations for HTTP links
gedmo/doctrine-extensions                v2.4.36  Doctrine2 behavioral extensions
incenteev/composer-parameter-handler     v2.1.3   Composer script handling your ignored parameter file
jdorn/sql-formatter                      v1.2.17  a PHP SQL highlighting library
knplabs/knp-menu                         2.3.0    An object oriented menu library
knplabs/knp-menu-bundle                  v2.2.1   This bundle provides an integration of the KnpMenu library
monolog/monolog                          1.23.0   Sends your logs to files, sockets, inboxes, databases and various web services
paragonie/random_compat                  v9.99.99 PHP 5.x polyfill for random_bytes() and random_int() from PHP 7
psr/cache                                1.0.1    Common interface for caching libraries
psr/container                            1.0.0    Common Container Interface (PHP FIG PSR-11)
psr/link                                 1.0.0    Common interfaces for HTTP links
psr/log                                  1.0.2    Common interface for logging libraries
psr/simple-cache                         1.0.1    Common interfaces for simple caching
sensio/distribution-bundle               v5.0.22  Base bundle for Symfony Distributions
sensio/framework-extra-bundle            v5.2.0   This bundle provides a way to configure your controllers with annotations
sensio/generator-bundle                  v3.1.7   This bundle generates code for you
sensiolabs/security-checker              v4.1.8   A security checker for your composer.lock
sonata-project/admin-bundle              3.38.0   The missing Symfony Admin Generator
sonata-project/block-bundle              3.12.1   Symfony SonataBlockBundle
sonata-project/cache                     2.0.1    Cache library
sonata-project/core-bundle               3.11.2   Symfony SonataCoreBundle
sonata-project/datagrid-bundle           2.3.1    Symfony SonataDatagridBundle
sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle 3.6.1    Symfony Sonata / Integrate Doctrine ORM into the SonataAdminBundle
sonata-project/exporter                  1.9.1    Lightweight Exporter library
sonata-project/intl-bundle               2.5.0    Symfony SonataIntlBundle
stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle          v1.3.0   Integration of the gedmo/doctrine-extensions with Symfony2
swiftmailer/swiftmailer                  v5.4.12  Swiftmailer, free feature-rich PHP mailer
symfony/asset                            v4.1.3   Symfony Asset Component
symfony/monolog-bundle                   v3.3.0   Symfony MonologBundle
symfony/phpunit-bridge                   v3.4.14  Symfony PHPUnit Bridge
symfony/polyfill-apcu                    v1.9.0   Symfony polyfill backporting apcu_* functions to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-ctype                   v1.9.0   Symfony polyfill for ctype functions
symfony/polyfill-intl-icu                v1.9.0   Symfony polyfill for intl's ICU-related data and classes
symfony/polyfill-mbstring                v1.9.0   Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension
symfony/polyfill-php56                   v1.9.0   Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 5.6+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-php70                   v1.9.0   Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 7.0+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-util                    v1.9.0   Symfony utilities for portability of PHP codes
symfony/security-acl                     v3.0.1   Symfony Security Component - ACL (Access Control List)
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle               v2.6.7   Symfony SwiftmailerBundle
symfony/symfony                          v3.4.14  The Symfony PHP framework
twig/extensions                          v1.5.2   Common additional features for Twig that do not directly belong in core
twig/twig                                v2.5.0   Twig, the flexible, fast, and secure template language for PHP
```

Comment: Version 9.99.99 random_compat is not supported in FOS 2.0. Can you downgrade the paragonie version?

Comment: I do it as Matias sad but I got another error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a known bug because `random_compat` library was recently updated to a weird `9.99.99` version for some reason, and a package has a dependency wrongly declared. What you can do is explicitly require `^2.0` version in your own project.

Run:

```
composer require paragonie/random_compat ^2.0
```

or you can modify the composer.json with

```
"require": {
    ...
    "paragonie/random_compat": "^2.0",
    ...
},
```

Then, install your bundle normally.

Comment: Matias with ^2.0 it wont work. 9.99.99 is above 2.0. You need to specify version 2. With ^2.0 is not an accepted answer

Comment: The `^` operator allows non breaking changes, i.e., anything between `2.0.0` and `3.0.0`, therefore, it will not install anything that does not start with 2. Read the composer [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret-version-range-) on the topic. This operator does not mean "greater than" as you seem to imply.